# Measurable Function Support

Tags: functional-analysis

Let be $u:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ a numerical measurable function. Let be $\tau_y u(x) = u(x-y)$. Then, the support($\tau_y u$)=$y$+support($u$).

I am trying:
If $x-y = c$ then $\tau_y u(x) = u(x-y)\iff \tau_y u(c+y) = u(c)$. Then support($\tau_y u$) $=\{c+y \in \Omega; u(c)\neq 0\}$. I think that $\{c+y \in \Omega; u(c)\neq 0\} = y + \{c \in \Omega; u(c)\neq 0\}$, but I don't know making a proof?

Comment: If $A$ is a set, the *definition* of $y+A$ is $\{y + x : x \in A\}$.

Comment: then, Is my response correctly correctly?

Answer (score 1):

There's a minor error: the domain of $\tau_y u$ is not $\Omega$, but $y+\Omega$.

Let $S=\{c \in \Omega; u(c)\neq 0\}$. The equality $$\{c+y :   c\in \Omega; u(c)\neq 0\} = y + S$$   a tautology, because (as Nate Eldredge said), $y+S$ is defined as as the set of points of the form $y+s$ where $s$ ranges over $S$.